# I need help deleting an entry from a list from a class function

Tags: python, list, class

In a program I am working on, whenever the player attacks an enemy, a little if statement runs to check the health of the target:

```
    def attack(self, target):
        target.stats.health = target.stats.health - self.stats.damage
        if target.stats.health <= 0:
            if isinstance(target, Enemy) == True:
                print(target.name, "has died")
                del #Something here to delete the target from the list of enemies
                #For example, in myPlayer.attack(enemies[0])
                #The target is enemies[0]
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print(target.name, "has", target.stats.health, "health left")
```

In my code, Instances of the Enemy class are created to create enemies, and those are all put into a list. What I want to do is delete the list entry if the target's health goes below. I know target itself is a reference to the instance of my Enemy, so using `del target` would just delete that reference. Is there a way that I can actually call the parameter entry or something and delete that? So if i type in `myPlayer.attack(enemies[x])`, the `del` function will run as `del enemies[x]`.

Comment: `enemies.remove(target)`, perhaps?  Using `del` would require that you know the index of the enemy within the list.

Comment: @jasonharper oh awesome, thanks. Something so simple completely slipped my mind!

Comment: I personally wouldn't write that in this function. The arguments are `self` and `target`, so taking an object out of the `enemies` list is a side effect. I would think about a higher-level process, maybe after all the actors have finished attacking, that would iterate through everyone with health and remove those that are dead. In an OOP sense, it's not the attacker's job to maintain the enemy list.